# High Definition tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I think we can merge / rename / remove some of the following HD tags:

- [hdtv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hdtv) x 93
- [high-definition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/high-definition) ([hd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hd)) x 57
- [hdvideo](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hdvideo) x 51

What do you think?

---

- <s>[hd-dvd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hd-dvd) x 5</s>
- <s>[fullhd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fullhd) x 2</s>

Comment: `[fullhd]` is already gone. The `[hd-dvd]` did exist but lost the war against Blu-ray. I cleared that tag as well.

Comment: `[hdvideo]` is distinct enough for me. It's about video > 720p resolution. HDTVs are a different thing altogether. The only tag that  is a little badly defined (*cough*) is `[high definition]` itself. I would propose going through that and coming up with more specific tags (and retagging into `[hdvideo]` and `[hdtv]` along the way).